# grep results with spaces and special chars

Tags: linux, grep, string, whitespace, bash-array

I am trying to grab results from lshw and add them to a a bash array so I can create a new string. I am using

```
lshw -class disk |egrep -A 7 .'-d' |grep 'product' |cut -b 17-
```

the output looks like this

```
Samsung SSD 850
Samsung SSD 840
ST8000AS0002-1NA
ST8000AS0002-1NA
Samsung SSD 870
Samsung SSD 870
ST8000VN0022-2EL
Flash Drive FIT
Flash Drive FIT
ST8000AS0002-1NA
ST8000VN0022-2EL
Samsung SSD 870
Samsung SSD 870
ST8000VN004-2M21
```

I tried to add this output to a bash array but each line with words separated by a space becomes an element in the array. You can also see the results from this command

```
for w in $(lshw -class disk |egrep -A 7 .'-d' |grep 'product' |cut -b 17-); do printf "$w \n" ;done
```

output

```
Samsung
SSD
850
Samsung
SSD
840
ST8000AS0002-1NA
ST8000AS0002-1NA
Samsung
SSD
870
Samsung
SSD
870
ST8000VN0022-2EL
Flash
Drive
FIT
Flash
Drive
FIT
ST8000AS0002-1NA
ST8000VN0022-2EL
Samsung
SSD
870
Samsung
SSD
870
ST8000VN004-2M21
```

How can I can I keep space separated lines as one one string?

Comment: That looks like a pretty fragile way of parsing the output of `lshw` - I'd suggest using its JSON output format with `jq` to extract the information, something like `lshw -class disk -json | jq -r 'select(.id == "disk") | .product'`

Comment: I don’t understand what result you want. You say “each line with words separated by a space becomes an element in the array” in a context that suggests that that’s what’s happening and it’s not what you want, but you also don’t seem individual words to be elements. Do you want the entire 30-word string to be a single element? If so, why are you trying to use an array? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

`mapfile` may be easiest.

```
mapfile -t myarray < <(lshw -class disk |egrep -A 7 .'-d' |grep 'product' |cut -b 17-)
```

But if you don't want to use a literal array and just want a loop over the results, you can just do:

```
lshw -class disk |egrep -A 7 .'-d' |grep 'product' |cut -b 17- | while read w ; do [something with w] ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote the command substitution:

```
# for w in "$(lshw -class disk |egrep -A 7 .'-d' |grep 'product' |cut -b 17-)"; do printf "$w \n" ;done
USB3.0 DISK00               
USB3.0 DISK01
USB3.0 DISK02
MS/MS-Pro
SD/MMC
Compact Flash
SM/xD-Picture
ST1000DM003-1CH1
WDC WD20EZAZ-00G
```

You then get:
"USB3.0 DISK00"
"USB3.0 DISK01"
...
being passed into the `for` loop.

Comment: That actually passes everything as a single multi-line string I think? See for example [bash pitfall #1](http://bash.cumulonim.biz/BashPitfalls.html#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: I'll be honest, I'd have never set it up that way, I just supplied a fix.  It works, as the example shows.  I haven't done any debugging though and it may be a one multi-line string rather that a number of discrete lines.  If I was doing for myself I'd pipe the output from the `lshw` into AWK and deal with it there, but then I'm old-fashioned!  Frabjous' second example is a better solution.